# Background color of check box sections in Jquery Mobile

Tags: html, css, background

Trying to create alternating background colors for my check box sections in my Jquery mobile site but the colors are just staying white... Tried a couple things and none worked the way I wanted.

```
<fieldset data-role="controlgroup" style="width:90%;">

<div class="OddBox"><input type="checkbox" name="checkbox1" id="checkbox1_0" class="custom" value="" />
<label for="checkbox1_0" style="color:rgba(4,96,46,1)">Call the Police Immediatly to report the accident and notify them of any medical assistence needed.</label></div>

<input type="checkbox" name="checkbox1" id="checkbox1_1" class="custom" value=""  />
<label for="checkbox1_1" style="color:rgba(4,96,46,1)">Turn on your 4-way flashers to warn other drivers.</label>

<input type="checkbox" name="checkbox1" id="checkbox1_2" class="custom, OddBox" value="" />
<label for="checkbox1_2" style="color:rgba(4,96,46,1)">Do not claim fault or responsibility.</label>

<input type="checkbox" name="checkbox1" id="checkbox1_3" class="custom" value="" />
<label for="checkbox1_3" style="color:rgba(4,96,46,1)">Remain calm and courteous.</label>
```

And my css

```
.OddBox{
    background-color: rgba(204,204,204,1);
}
```

I tried using a div wrapper and adding the style right to the input line of code. When I style the label it ands up just changing the color behind the text.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

First change your HTML so your input and labels are in the same row. Like this:

```
<fieldset data-role="controlgroup" style="width:90%;">
    <div class="OddBox">
        <div class="form_row">
            <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox1" id="checkbox1_0" class="custom" value="" />
            <label for="checkbox1_0" style="color:rgba(4,96,46,1)">Call the Police Immediatly to report the accident and notify them of any medical assistence needed.</label>
        </div>
        <div class="form_row">
            <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox1" id="checkbox1_1" class="custom" value="" />
            <label for="checkbox1_1" style="color:rgba(4,96,46,1)">Turn on your 4-way flashers to warn other drivers.</label>
        </div>
        <div class="form_row">
            <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox1" id="checkbox1_2" class="custom, OddBox" value="" />
            <label for="checkbox1_2" style="color:rgba(4,96,46,1)">Do not claim fault or responsibility.</label>
        </div>
        <div class="form_row">
            <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox1" id="checkbox1_3" class="custom" value="" />
            <label for="checkbox1_3" style="color:rgba(4,96,46,1)">Remain calm and courteous.</label>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Now you can simply target that `div` as you want. In your case, something like this:

```
.form_row:nth-child(odd) {
    background-color: rgba(204, 204, 204, 1)
}
```

I forgot: here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gq41mdc1/) for you to preview and play around:

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can do this..

you did prob do this with shifting `background position` and hiding the actual check box

or use the `:before` and `:after` to add contents and style to replace the check box see this for example

http://cssdeck.com/labs/css-checkbox-styles